# Interpretating 1D-motion properties described by $x(t) = t - \sin{t}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

A question in the third chapter of *Exemplar Problems in Physics for Class XI* goes thus:

> (3.9) For the one-dimensional motion described by $ x = t - \sin{t} $
>
> (a) $x(t) > 0$ for all $t>0$.
>
> (b) $v(t) > 0$ for all $t>0$.
>
> (c) $a(t) > 0$ for all $t>0$.
>
> (d) $v(t)$ lies between $0$ and $2$.

The answers are *(a)* and *(d)*.

I do not quite understand how they've arrived at the answers despite taking the first- and second-order derivatives of $x(t)$. A detailed explanation as to why the two options are correct would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

$$v(t) = x'(t) = 1 - cos \;t$$

Since $-cos \;t$ lies between -1 and 1, then $1 - cos \;t$ lies between 0 and 2. Therefore $v(t) = x'(t) \geq 0$. Note that beacuse $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(t) > 0$ in $(0, 2\pi)$, by a corollary of Lagrange Theorem we conclude that $x(t) > 0$ in $(0, 2\pi)$. Thus, $x(t) > 0$ for all $t > 0$ beacuse the derivative is non-negative.

Clearly (b) is false and (c) is false beacuse $a(t) = v'(t) = sin \;t$, which can be any value in $[-1, 1]$